# Adapter of type XmlAdapter<String, JAXBElement<DateTimeType>>

Tags: xml, jaxb, java-8, jaxbelement

As an workaround I have wrote a Adapter of type `XmlAdapter<String, JAXBElement<DateTimeType>>` but I understand i need to write a code which will directly convert JAXBElement to appropriate XML element in string form.  I looked through the net for the same but no luck.

My question is how can I convert a JaxbElement to Corresponding xml element string. 
I am using Java 8.

Thanks in advance.